# Jenkins Pipeline pass String array to function

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins pipeline and I want pass String array to local function; i try with a Strinf is ok but not with a String array.

**in pipeline:**:

```
stage('package') {
    steps {
        executeModuleScripts(["module1", "module2"])
    }
}
```

**at the end of pipeline:**

```
void executeModuleScripts(allModules) {

    allModules.each { module ->
    
        String gitFolder = "${module}"
          
        script {
            stage(module) {
                bat 'xcopy "' + gitFolder + '/foo/*" "temp/PUB/foo" /C /S /I /F /H'
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

I have this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: operation for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be like :

**Scripted Pipeline**

```
node {
    stage('package') {
        executeModuleScripts(['01','02'])
    }
}
void executeModuleScripts(allModules) {
    allModules.each { module ->
        script {
            stage(module) {
                // sh "cp -R ${module}/foo/* temp/PUB/foo"
                bat 'xcopy "' + module + '/foo/*" "temp/PUB/foo" /C /S /I /F /H'
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

**Declarative Pipeline**

```
void executeModuleScripts(allModules) {
    allModules.each { module ->
        script {
            stage(module) {
                // sh "cp -R ${module}/foo/* temp/PUB/foo"
                bat 'xcopy "' + module + '/foo/*" "temp/PUB/foo" /C /S /I /F /H'
            }
        }

    }   
}

pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('package') {
            steps {
                executeModuleScripts(['A','B'])
            }
        }
    }
}
```